# Could not connect with MongoLab database URl using node.js and Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mlab

I could not connect to MongoDB which is present in MongoLAB . I have one `MEAN` app and I have deployed in heroku. When I am trying to connect with database but could not. The logs are given below.

```
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...

2017-07-31T11:46:48.243603+00:00 app[web.1]:     at module.exports (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:59:13)

2017-07-31T11:46:48.243605+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.MongoClient.connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:113:3)

2017-07-31T11:46:48.243604+00:00 app[web.1]:     at connect (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:289:16)

2017-07-31T11:46:48.243606+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (/app/node_modules/thunky/index.js:13:3)

2017-07-31T11:46:48.243606+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongojs/lib/database.js:29:15

2017-07-31T11:46:48.243607+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Collection._getConnection (/app/node_modules/thunky/index.js:27:3)

2017-07-31T11:46:48.243608+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Collection._getCollection (/app/node_modules/mongojs/lib/collection.js:17:10)

2017-07-31T11:46:48.243609+00:00 app[web.1]:     at getCursor (/app/node_modules/mongojs/lib/collection.js:32:10)

2017-07-31T11:46:48.243610+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (/app/node_modules/thunky/index.js:13:3)

2017-07-31T11:46:48.243609+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongojs/lib/cursor.js:12:5

2017-07-31T11:46:48.244240+00:00 app[web.1]: [0mPOST /login [31m500 [0m30.134 ms - 22[0m

Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
```

My code is below:

```
var mongoJs=require('mongojs');
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var database='FGDP';
var collections=['f_users'];
var MONGOLAB_URI="mongodb://username:password@ds127153.mlab.com:27153/fgdp";
var db=mongoJs(MONGOLAB_URI, collections);
var ses;
exports.userlogin=function(req,res){
    var username=req.body.user_name;
    var password=req.body.user_pass;
   // console.log('pass'+typeof(password));
    //var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, 'lexelPass');
    //var pass=ciphertext.toString();
    db.f_users.findOne({'login_name':username},function(err,docs){
        console.log('err',err);
        if(!err){
            if(docs){
                var pass=docs.password;
                var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(pass.toString(), 'lexelPass');
                var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
                if(plaintext==password){
                   req.session.email=docs.email;
                   req.session.name=docs.name;
                   req.session.login_name=docs.login_name;
                   req.session.status=docs.status;
                   req.session.user_type=docs.user_type;
                   res.send(docs); 
                }else{
                   res.send("Login failed");
                }
            }
        }
        if(err){
            res.send("Login failed");
        }
    })
}
```

That database and collection is present in mongoLAB. I need to connect it through mongojs. Actally I have a login App and I could not login.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like

```
var db = mongoJs(MONGOLAB_URI);
db.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('database connected')
});
```

Comment: Then how to connect collections.

Comment: Ok let me to test and let you know.

Comment: I could not found this log message in heroku.